# 3 Servers, Infiniband, without IB switch

Tags: subnet, infiniband

I took a look every post related similar questions but they didn't give me clear answer.

Our planned system consists of three machines named n1, n2, and n3. The connection is set up as follows:

n1 ---- n2(sm) ---- n3

Our original plan was to purchase two single-port ConnectX-6 VPI adapter cards and one dual-port adapter.

For n1 and n3, each has a single adapter, while n3 has a dual-port adapter.

However, due to difficulties in sourcing dual-mode cards, our supplier has delivered 4 single-port cards instead.

Currently, we have one single-port card installed in both n1 and n3, and two single-port cards installed in n2.

We intend to use OpenSM on n2 to establish direct connections to n1 and n3. However, our supplier has recommended an InfiniBand switch, stating that the subnet manager cannot manage this setup.

Upon reviewing the documentation, I believe that using OpenSM to manage multiple subnets should be sufficient, allowing us to use the setup without the need for a switch. This would significantly affect the cost.

Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?
Or should I have to purchase IB switch for set these up?
[They have sent a quotation that exceeds $20,000]

I would appreciate your response after verification.

Thanks in advance.

Edit.
n1 doesn't need to connect to n3 at all.

Comment: The most hopeful link is https://support.mellanox.com/s/article/MLNX2-117-2650kn

Comment: This is very possible, I know as I buy lots of Infinidat storage arrays and this is exactly when they do for their RDMA-backed caching engine. I'll ask them how they're linked and get back to you.

Comment: @Chopper3 You saved me!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not all of your questions but as promised here's how Infinidat link their three-controller storage arrays together with Infiniband, this image is from one of their documents, if you look at the diagram you'll see that they're just used dual-port adapters, I'd never have thought this would work but it clearly does, I've bought over 150 of their arrays over the last seven+ years and it's rock solid.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate with your answer @Chopper3, Knowing that is able to be is very helpful to me.